# httpclient processor `replyExpression` variables

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm building the pipeline with spring cloud stream starters and `httpclient`processor is one of the steps. My requirement is to invoke the remote http server and **enrich**  the original message with the response.
The problem is that `httpclient`processor doesn't allow to propagate attributes from original message, it only allows to evaluate the message expression based on reply body.

I was suggested to store some attributes in message headers before `httpclient`, but getting `MessageHeaders is immutable` exception.

So, basically, I can't proceed the pipeline after `httpclient` as I'm lacking the needed attributes from original message.

See the detailed discussion in [github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/issues/274)

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Artem in github, you can use header enricher there. Check this one as an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999528/spring-integration-transformer-and-header-enricher)